# Lucene Query (Term-/BooleanQuery) returns false positives

Tags: java, lucene

I'm trying to do some language analysis and have written a small "sentence store" based on a Lucene index. What it does in splitting text into sentences and store them (each) in a document.

Here's how I store my sentences:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new StringField("language", getLanguage(), Store.YES));
doc.add(new TextField("text", getLiteralValue(), Store.YES));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < getTokens().size(); i++) {
    doc.add(new StringField("term_" + i, getTokens().get(i).getLiteralValue(), Store.YES));
    doc.add(new StringField("terms", getTokens().get(i).getLiteralValue(), Store.YES));
    doc.add(new StringField("pos_" + i, getTokens().get(i).getPoS(), Store.YES));

    sb.append(getTokens().get(i).getPoS()).append(" ");
}

doc.add(new IntField("length", getTokens().size(), Store.YES));
doc.add(new TextField("pos", sb.toString(), Store.YES));
```

The result is a construct where I can query for part-of-spech tag sequences e.g. "JJ NN NN" (I use a WhiteSpaceAnalyzer) and get sentences as results (which I then parse into Pojos).

I store all the tokens in a separate multi valued ***StringField*** ("terms") and was hoping to be able to run queries against it to find documents containing specific terms.

***I intentionally don't wish to use lucene to tokenize the whole sentence, because I already get single tokens as input and want to be able to easily iterate over them.***

For some reason, when searching with a TermQuery, results come up that don't contain the terms I'm searching for e.g.:

```
TermQuery tq = new TermQuery(new Term("terms", "hierarchy"));
```

would return documents with text like:

> Review & completion of the document.

```
Document<
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<language:en> stored,indexed,tokenized<text:Review & completion of the document.>
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<term_0:Review> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<terms:Review>
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<pos_0:NOUN> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<term_1:&>
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<terms:&> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<pos_1:CONJ>
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<term_2:completion> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<terms:completion>
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<pos_2:NOUN> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<term_3:of>
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<terms:of> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<pos_3:ADP>
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<term_4:the> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<terms:the>
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<pos_4:DET> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<term_5:document>
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<terms:document> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<pos_5:NOUN>
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<term_6:.> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<terms:.>
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<pos_6:.> stored<length:7> stored,indexed,tokenized<pos:NOUN CONJ NOUN ADP DET NOUN . >

>
```

There no value of "terms" that looks even remotely like the string "hiearchy", so how comes this document pops up in the search results?

Comment: I suggest you to see the content of returned documents to have a glue. Check if this index was previously charged with some data. Any way, it's really difficult to analyse unknowing your dataset and Lucene version.

Comment: Juliano, as far as the content goes, I've posted the returned document above. It's the same with all of them. None of the returned documents contain the searched term. Also, I've tested with lucene, 3.6, 4.10.2 and several versions in between. Same behavior for all of them.

Comment: @Michael I can't replicate your problem. This example finds no match for 'hierarchy' and 1 match for 'JJ': http://codepaste.net/28gezg I suspect your problem is in your own code, not Lucene

Comment: @bcoughlan you're right. Figures one of my Collectors was using the index searcher to fetch documents, thus returning not the documents it was actually hitting, but more or less random documents from the overall index.